# How do I plot the integral of e^(-t^2) from x=0 to x=3 in Python?

Tags: python, math, plot, physics, integral

I need to both calculate and plot the integral below in Python:

integral of the function e^(-t^2) from x=0 to x=3

[image]

So far I've managed to calculate the integral using Simpson's rule. The next bit which I'm struggling with is plotting the integral of e^(-t^2) vs x from x=0 to x=3 (see the image above).

Here's the code I've written to calculate the integral -

```
from math import exp

def f(t):
    return exp(-(t**2))

a = 0
b = 3
h = 0.1
N = int((b-a)/h)
s_even = 0
s_odd = 0

for k in range(1,N,2):
    s_odd += f(a+k*h)

for k in range(2,N,2):
    s_even += f(a+k*h)

s = f(a) + f(b) + 4*s_odd + 2*s_even
Integral = h*s/3
print(Integral)
```

How do I then create a graph of this integral?

Comment: Please try to find a more concrete title. What exactly are you struggeling with? Can you formulate a single question, so that the answer would help you?

Comment: If you are using version 3.2 or later then you can use math.erf for this; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help Red Cricket. It looks like you may have graphed the function e^(-t^2) rather than the integral of that function. Nonetheless, I think I've worked it out; I've discovered scipy has an integrate function:

```
from math import exp
from numpy import arange
from scipy import integrate

def f(t):
    return exp(-(t**2))

a = 0
b = 3
h = 0.1
N = int((b-a)/h)

s_even = 0
s_odd = 0

for k in range(1,N,2):
    s_odd += f(a+k*h)

for k in range(2,N,2):
    s_even += f(a+k*h)

s = f(a) + f(b) + 4*s_odd + 2*s_even
I = h*s/3

function = []
x = []
for t in arange(0,4,h):
    function.append(f(t))
for i in arange(0,4,h):
    x.append(i)

function_int = integrate.cumtrapz(function,x,initial=0)

plot(x,function_int)
show()
print(I)
```

This produces a graph of the integral and prints the final value of the integral itself. Hooray!

Answer (score 0):

Here's a script I wrote that performs your calculation and plots it using [PyQtGraph](http://www.pyqtgraph.org/):

```
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui, QtCore
import pyqtgraph as pg

from math import exp

class I:

    def f(self,t):
        return exp(-(t**2))

    def __init__(self, a = 0, b = 3, h = 0.1):
        N = int((b-a)/h)
        s_even = s_odd = 0
        for k in range(1,N,2):
            s_odd += self.f(a+k*h)

        for k in range(2,N,2):
            s_even += self.f(a+k*h)

        s = self.f(a) + self.f(b) + 4*s_odd + 2*s_even
        self.I = h*s/3

    def __str__(self):
        return "I: %s" % self.I

def plot(array):
    app = QtGui.QApplication([])
    win = pg.GraphicsWindow(title="Basic plotting examples")
    win.resize(1000,600)
    win.setWindowTitle('pyqtgraph example: Plotting')

    # Enable antialiasing for prettier plots
    pg.setConfigOptions(antialias=True)

    p1 = win.addPlot(title="Basic array plotting", y=array)

    QtGui.QApplication.instance().exec_()

def main():
    a=0
    b=a+0.001
    points=[]
    while(a<3):
        points.append(I(a,b).I)
        a=b
        b=a+0.001
    plot(points)


## Start Qt event loop unless running in interactive mode or using pyside.
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is the graph it draws:

[image]

Comment: From your graph it looks like you are plotting something like the exponential function itself `e^(-x**2)` rather than its integral.

Comment: I am just demonstrating how one can create a graph in Python by plotting what the OP states to be the integral.   If it is not an integral hopefully the OP will see your comment and realize his mistake.